# How to detect if Windows is 64x or 86x via Lingo (Adobe Director)

Tags: windows, x86, 64-bit, lingo, adobe-director

I was wondering if its possible to detect if a costumer's Windows is 64x or 86x based via Director. The reason for this is that some Xtras don't work as intended when running on a 64x windows, and I wanted to create 2 versions of my program for better compatibility.

If possible, I wanted a code based solution, with no other program involved other than Director.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [BuddyAPI](http://www.mods.com.au/budapi/) and the baVersion( "Wow64" ) code.
this will return 1 if running as a 32 bit application under 64 bit Windows. Since projectors are only 32 bit applications, this will be true if Windows is 64 bit. It will return 0 if running under 32 bit Windows.
baVersion ("64Bit" ) will return 1 if running under a 64 bit processor, regardless of the Windows version.